# Place Order and Create account is not working after installing SMTP Extension. Magento 2.2.10

Tags: magento2, customer-account, smtp, place-order

I installed the [Magetop_Smtp](https://www.magetop.com/magento-2-smtp-extension.html) extension but when I installed this extension then When I clicked on *Place Order* Button in checkout then **nothing happens** also when I create a new *account* of user then it gives me an error `Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Application_Resource_Mail' not found in C:\xamppp\htdocs\magentoo\app\code\Magetop\Smtp\Mail\Rse\Mail.php on line 31` What is the issue n how can I sort this.
[image]

Comment: Try other SMTP Mageplaza or MagePal

Comment: I tried Mageplaza one as well in that same issue occurs

Comment: `' does not match the expected structure for a DNS hostname, '' does not appear to be a valid URI hostname, '' does not appear to be a valid local network name magento 2` this issue on MagePal testing

Comment: I'm using Magepal gmail its working no issue for me. Your email address has to be less secure in order to use SMTP otherwise it will failed to send authentication.

Comment: Yeah I just installed Magepal but I test it then it give me the above issue... can you please share you configuration it will help me that where I'm doing mistake

Comment: Well Well.... Its quite complicated cause I'm also having some problems I've couple of google accounts having same configurations but one of them is working for SMTP. Still you can give a try by https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en

Comment: ok so now I get some new error `Authentication Credentials Invalid`

Comment: Do not change any default configurations only add your email address and password like, http://tinyurl.com/y25bjffz

Comment: @Vivek can you please check the question again I updated it

Comment: You need to remove/disable other SMTP not work when others activated. Set configuration like I said above. Username will be your email address and password and one more important thing Magepal Gmailsmtp only work with GMail not other providers.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this issue, its caused by email attachment.

If you using any extension for attachment try to disable it first and try the process again.

If the source is email extension so you to contact the publisher of that extension for the support

Comment: No I do not use anything... I think but not sure that this is the version issue

Comment: on which version you were working on this